# INSERT ERROR: Select isn't matching definition of columns

Tags: error-handling, insert

I have a query that ranks call centers based on a couple of performance metrics.  I am attempting to modify this query by adding in the number of surveys each center received.

After adding the "Total" or "Surveys" column in the appropriate places, I am receiving the error:

```
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Can you tell me where I am mis-defining the column?  I will post the relevant parts of the code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ACSResults') 
IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ACSResults 
CREATE TABLE #ACSResults (AreaID VARCHAR(4), Location VARCHAR(50), Surveys VARCHAR(6), MonthName VARCHAR(6), RepResolve FLOAT, ERP FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #ACSResults 
      SELECT 
        a.area,
        a.location,
        COUNT(a.IVRCallID) as Surveys,
        a.monthname,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a.RepResolve IN ('1','0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.RepResolve = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.RepResolve IN ('1','0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT) END AS REPRESOLVE,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a.ERP IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8', '9', '10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.ERP IN ('8', '9', '10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT) / CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN a.ERP in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT))END AS ERP

FROM (SELECT
... 
acs.IVRCallID, 
...

FROM dbCustomerSurvey.Detail.vwAfterCallSurvey acs 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Summary.vwEmployeeHistory eh ON acs.EmployeeID = eh.EmployeeID AND acs.OfferDate BETWEEN eh.StartDate AND eh.EndDate 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwName Rep ON eh.EmployeeID = Rep.EmployeeID 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwName Sup ON eh.BottomUp01ID = Sup.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwName Mgr ON eh.BottomUp02ID = Mgr.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwName Dir ON eh.BottomUp03ID = Dir.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwVirtualLocation vl ON eh.VirtualLocationID = vl.VirtualLocationID 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwDepartment d ON eh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwPeopleSoftDepartment psd ON eh.PeopleSoftDepartmentID = psd.PeopleSoftDepartmentID
WHERE acs.CurrentStatus IN ('Completed', 'COMP') and acs.surveytype IN ('ACS_FCR_Rep_Perform', 'ACS_FCR_Rep_Perform-prepaid', 'ACS_Rep_Perform_BSC2', 'ACS_Rep_Perform_Gov') AND acs.OfferDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) a 

...

group by 
a.area,
a.location,
a.monthname

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------REPEAT TABLE------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HRRep') 
IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HRRep 
CREATE TABLE #HRRep (AreaID VARCHAR(4), Location VARCHAR(50), Surveys VARCHAR(6), MonthName VARCHAR(6), HourRepeatPercent FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #HRRep (AreaID, Location, Surveys, MonthName, HourRepeatPercent) 
      Select eh.AreaID, vl.VirtualLocationDescription, COUNT(acs1.IVRCallID) as Surveys, Month (acs.statdate) AS MonthName,

Cast(Sum(acs.Repeats2Hr)as float) /nullif(Sum(acs.Calls2Hr), 0) as 'HourRepeatPercent'

From dbReportSummary.ReportSummary.vwRepeatCalls2Hr acs with (NoLOCK)
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Summary.vwEmployeeHistory eh with (NoLOCK) ON acs.EmployeeID = eh.EmployeeID AND acs.StatDate BETWEEN eh.StartDate AND eh.EndDate 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwVirtualLocation vl ON eh.VirtualLocationID = vl.VirtualLocationID 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwDepartment d ON eh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID 
LEFT JOIN dbEmployee.Config.vwPeopleSoftDepartment psd ON eh.PeopleSoftDepartmentID = psd.PeopleSoftDepartmentID
LEFT JOIN dbCustomerSurvey.Detail.vwAfterCallSurvey acs1 ON acs.EmployeeID=acs1.EmployeeID and acs1.OfferDate BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate

...

Group by eh.AreaID, vl.VirtualLocationDescription, Month (acs.statdate)


SELECT a.Location, a.Surveys, a.RepResolve, a.RRRank, a.ERP, a.ERPRank,a.HourRepeatPercent, a.RepeatRank, (a.RRRank + a.ERPRank+a.RepeatRank) as 'Total Rank Points', Rank() OVER(ORDER BY (a.RRRank + a.ERPRank+a.RepeatRank) ASC, a.RepResolve DESC) AS 'Overall Rank'
From(
            SELECT a.Location, a.Surveys, a.RepResolve, Rank() OVER(ORDER BY a.RepResolve DESC) AS RRRank, a.ERP, Rank() OVER(ORDER BY a.ERP DESC) AS ERPRank, b.HourRepeatPercent, Rank() OVER(ORDER BY b.HourRepeatPercent ASC) AS RepeatRank
            FROM #ACSResults AS A
            Left Join #HRRep AS B on a.areaid=b.areaid and a.monthname=b.monthname and a.location=b.location and a.Surveys=b.Surveys
) a
Group BY  a.Location, a.Surveys, a.RepResolve, a.RRRank, a.ERP, a.ERPRank,a.HourRepeatPercent, a.RepeatRank, (a.RRRank + a.ERPRank+a.RepeatRank)
```

"..." denotes a chunk of code I deleted due to irrelevance.  Please let me know if I have not posted enough.  I can post more but heard complaints about posting too much in the past.

Comment: is This  the code that "fails"? `INSERT INTO #HRRep (AreaID, Location, Surveys, MonthName, HourRepeatPercent)`

Comment: It's actually 'INSERT INTO #ACSResults' that's giving me the error.  Not sure if #HRRep would be related since we're joining the 2 tables into one.  Sorry, a bit novice over here.

Comment: Execute this code and then try again: `DROP TABLE #ACSResults DROP TABLE #HRRep`

Comment: I don't understand how I missed that!  I even had a "if not null DROP TABLE" in there.  Oh well...we're getting results now.  Thank you so much!  If you post as an answer I will accept. 

Quick side question though, any idea why the "HourRepeatPercent" column is now showing up as completely null?  Every center shows null under that column.  I didn't think I had messed with that metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this code and then try again:

```
DROP TABLE #ACSResults 
DROP TABLE #HRRep
```

Comment: Thank you, Pabloker! Was wondering if you could tell my why the HourRepeatPercent Column is now null? (the info being called in the #HRRep table).  Sorry to hijack, after this snag I will be good to go.

Comment: Correction...figured it out.  Thanks again for all your help, Pabloker!